# Random connection drops with Azure Firewall - no pattern observable

Tags: azure, nginx, networking, tcp

The company I work for has a web application running solidly in our Hosted Datacentre for years, no hiccups. Using route 53, NGINX, etc.

We started building in Azure recently, and are noticing weird connection drops in random times. No pattern we can find except that, the drops only occur with the Azure firewall involved.

Has anyone encountered this? The client-side traffic flow is as follows:

Client Machine --> Route 53 --> Azure Firewall --> NGINX server --> Azure application server

We've done multiple connection tests with our apps - to keep it short, internally within the Azure environment, there's no problems.

Connection tests involved just the app server stack, just the internal NGINX server, route 53 + nginx server (bypassing firewall) is fine.

It seems something specific with the firewall and how it keeps connections. I could provide some scrubbed logs, but not sure where to look.

I've found this, not sure it could be related:
https://github.com/wbuchwalter/azure-content/blob/master/includes/guidance-tcp-session-timeout-include.md

Comment: Are you using this [Azure firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/)? Have you tried to monitor [Azure Firewall using firewall logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/logs-and-metrics).

Comment: we tried that, nothing observable!

Comment: Try to capture the network traces between the Route 53 and NGINX server?

Comment: didn't work. since the FW was only being used for port forwarding, we've bypassed it and that solved the issue. i suspect nginx didn't like the ip encapsulation from the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

since the FW was only being used for port forwarding, we've bypassed it and that solved the issue. i suspect nginx didn't like the requests or didn't know how to forward back through to the firewall because, of, ip encapsulation from the firewall. there may be a way to solve that but we didn't investigate further.